# How can i call my routes from express app instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a cronjob on my server that interfaces my REST Api running in a different node process like this:

```
request({
    url: 'http://example.com/abc',
    method: "POST",
    json: data
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

This blocks my User interface while the cronjob is sending data.

My idea was to export the app and require it in my cronjob and call the routes directly from there.
Similar to what you do when using [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest).

The problem is i can't figure out how to call the route.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// ...
module.exports = app;
```

**cronjob.js**

```
const app = require('../../app');

function pushIt(url, data, apiKey) {
    // make POST request to app here
}
```

Is this possible somehow? The reason I want to do is I want to have the load of the POST request in the cronjob process with its own app instance.
So that the public api is not slowed down when running the cronjob.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you are posting from one process (cron) to another (api) and you would like to make (cron) post to itself instead of posting to (api)? Do you need the data at (api)?

Comment: I would like to have a unique interface (api) for cron and the website frontend. But I don't want the cronjob to slow down the frontend. Yes data is sent in the POST body and needed at the api.